# How can you apply a jQuery event handler to act only on the div the user is in?

Tags: jquery

Here's what I'm trying to do, I have several multiple choice questions that are all set up using the same HTML code, with the same class name (a div for the question with 4 paragraphs within the div for the answer choices).

I want to use jQuery to assign a class called 'selected' to the answer choice (paragraph) that the user clicks on. And then once they've clicked on their answer choice, turn off the click event for that question only.  But I'm not sure how to get it to apply to only the div that the user is clicking in and not the entire page. Here's what I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function selecting() {
        $('.choices p').on('click', function() {
            $('.choices p').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });

        $('.submit').click(function() {
            $('.choices p').off('click');
        });
    };

    selecting();
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to disable the click event after a selection is made? What if someone accidentally clicks the wrong answer? Then they cannot correct it.

Comment: Rather than *describing* the HTML to us, it would help if you could *show* it to us ideally an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) representative sample (not the entirety of your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the current `.choices` element and then target the `p` element from that element only like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function selecting() {
    $('.choices p').on('click', function() {
      $(this).closest('.choices').find('p').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');

    });

    $('.submit').click(function() {
      $(this).prev('.choices').find('p').off('click');
    });
  };

  selecting();

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
p {
  border: 1px dashed green;
  width: 49.8%;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.center {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 2% auto;
}
.question {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
.selected {
  background: yellow;
}
.move {
  width: 15%;
  min-height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100%;
}
input[type='submit'] {
  width: 15%;
  min-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 42.5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100%;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='section' id='s1'>
  <div class='center' id='center1'>
    <div class='question' id='q1'>
    </div>
    <div class='choices' id='choices1'>
      <p class='p-choice' class='a'>Choice A</p>
      <p class='p-choice' class='b'>Choice B</p>
      <p class='p-choice' class='c'>Choice C</p>
      <p class='p-choice' class='d'>Choice D</p>
    </div>
    <!--<div class='move'>Submit</div>-->
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' class='submit' />
  </div>
</div>

<div class='section' id='s2'>
  <div class='center' id='center2'>
    <div class='question' id='q2'>
    </div>
    <div class='choices' id='choices2'>
      <p class='p-choice' class='a'>Choice A</p>
      <p class='p-choice' class='b'>Choice B</p>
      <p class='p-choice' class='c'>Choice C</p>
      <p class='p-choice' class='d'>Choice D</p>
    </div>
    <!--<div class='move'>Submit</div>-->
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' class='submit' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked for adding and removing the class 'selected', but now the clicking on the Submit button doesn't turn off clicking.  I copied and pasted everything into jsfiddle so you can see http://jsfiddle.net/b4tz9w4k/

Comment: @aprobert because the `.choices` is the previous sibling of the button not an ancestor